# Find a void pointer in an container of MyClass pointers?

Tags: c++, casting, undefined-behavior, void-pointers

I have a pointer `void* p` that points to a variable of unknown type, as well as a container `std::set<MyClass*> c` populated with `MyClass` pointers. Is there some way to find out whether `c` contains `p` (i.e. whether it contains a pointer that points to the same memory address as `p`) without manually looping through the elements in `c`, that doesn’t cause undefined behavior? (Note that I’m not going to dereference `p` if I don’t find it in `c`.)

Also, I assume that casting `p` to `MyClass*` would cause undefined behavior if `p` would point to a variable of a datatype that was not related but to `MyClass`, but maybe that’s not the case?

Comment: Note that a `std::set` of pointers uses the ***pointer itself*** as the "key", not what it points to. So all you need to do is call its [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) function to see if the set contains the pointer.

Comment: Could you change to `std::set<MyClass*, std::less<void>>` ? Then you could use the find method taking void pointer as comparer would be *"transparent"*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: but pointer types differ... and the cast might be UB IIRC.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think your suggestion may be a winner! (You should write it as an actual answer.) I will have to try it when I get back to work on Monday.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: I have already posted an answer ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Oops, I might have missed that part of your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that casting `p` to `MyClass*` would cause undefined behavior if [..]

It is pedantically correct that it might cause UB.

But should probably work in practice (Joy of UB).

> Is there some way to find out whether c contains p [..] without manually looping through the elements in c.

`std::find_if` or `std::binary_search` can be used with appropriate predicate to find it in linear time (`std::set::iterator` is not a random iterator, so "falsify" `binary_search` complexity).

If you can change your container to:

- `std::set<MyClass*, std::less<void>>`, then you might safely use `std::set::find`
  thanks to transparent comparer.
- sorted `std::vector<MyClass*>`, then you might use `std::binary_search` with correct complexity.

Comment: "Should probably work" isn't really reassuring when it comes to code with undefined behavior. It may at any moment compile into something that produces a bug, which may besides be very difficult to find since your program now does something different than what is described in the code.

Comment: I agree that *"should probably work"* is dangerous, but unfortunately several UB works or seems to works in practice.

Comment: Full context is in the question :-). I changed the part of the quote. Hope it has enough context by itself now for you.

Comment: Specifying a comparison functor by using `std::set<MyClass*, std::less<void>>` or even `std::set<MyClass*, std::less<>>` instead of `std::set<MyClass*>` worked! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can cast `void*` to another pointer safely, but should not dereference it. Looking up a pointer in `std::set<T*>` doesn't dereference the pointer (unless you specify a custom compare predicate that does).

Pedantically, the C++ standard says that just loading an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour. However, that is a provision for hardware architectures with [segmented addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode#Segment_addressing) (x86 real mode), where loading a pointer loads a part of its value into a segment register and that may cause a hardware trap. In modern architectures with flat memory models this restriction does not apply, loading any pointer value is well defined because that is just a load into a general purpose CPU register.

Something like:

```
MyClass* find(std::set<MyClass*> const& c, void* p) {
    auto found = c.find(static_cast<MyClass*>(p));
    return found != c.end() ? *found : nullptr;
}
```

You can use it like:

```
std::set<MyClass*> c;
void* p = ...;
if(MyClass* q = find(c, p))
   // p is found and is q
```

Comment: would `dynamic_cast` be a cleaner method (albeit a slower one)?

Comment: @TvanB `dynamic_cast` requires the argument's static type to have virtual functions, which `void` doesn't have.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin If the C++ standard says that just loading an invalid pointer is undefined behavior, I'm afraid that even if the hardware still behaves as expected when you compile the code without optimization, the compiler may still generate [unexpected assembly code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#UB_and_optimization) when you do use optimization (which you usually want to do). This should be reason enough to make sure you code does not have any undefined behavior.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You are right in general. However, I do not see how that applies here, that `static_cast` is no-op in assembly. You may like to come up with an example.

Comment: I don't know enough about compilers to know if this could go wrong. Besides, I don't see why I should need come up with an example; it's I who am writing the code, so I think it's you who needs to convince me that a `static_cast` is fail safe in this case, especially since you advocate using code that may possibly produce undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, `static_cast` doesn't produce any assembly code directly in this case. However, if performing the cast is undefined behavior, it will effectively tell the compiler that the referenced variable is a `MyClass` object or an object of a derived class, which may or may not enable the compiler to make additional optimizations—which would most likely be invalid if the presumption is false. Now, I don't know if the compiler could use that presumption to make any optimization. Do you?

Comment: Well, if you cast from `void *`, `static_cast` will not make any pointer adjustment because it has not information about the original type and **assume that the programmer know** that the cast is correct (essentially cast back to the type from which void pointer was obtained)

Comment: @HelloGoodbye There are no facts or insights in your vague conjectures pertaining to this question. Please stop imagining problems and spreading FUD here.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin All I asked of you was to prove that your suggestion is safe to use as I'm not convinced it is.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, you should be able to do it (see other anser and comments) but you need to be aware of some pitfalls.

If you have class that derive from another class (say `OtherClass`) and `MyClass`, then you need to ensure that `p` point to `MyClass` part and not `OtherClass`. While you won't have undefined behavior, you won't find the item.

```
class OtherClass { int someData; };
class WontWork : public OtherClass, public MyClass { };

auto *w = new WontWork();
c.insert(w);
void *p = w;
```

In that case, you won't find `p` in the set as the value of `p` is different from the one inserted in the set (after implicit cast to `MyClass *`).

To make the code work, you need `p` to point to `MyClass` part by doing something like:

```
void *p = static_cast<MyClass *>(w);
```

or

```
MyClass *mc = w;
p = mc;
```

But then, you have to ensure that you don't use `p` as if it was of type `OtherClass` or `WontWork` elsewhere in the code.

If possible, it would be preferable to avoid `void *` entirely by fixing declarations.

Comment: Well, now I don't have a pointer to an object of a class that derives from `MyClass`, but a `void` pointer. Also, see my comment on the other answer explaining why casting the `void` pointer might not be a desirable solution.

Comment: While optimization might cause undefined behavior because you lie to the compiler, in practice, there are far more chance that something goes wrong because of casting can hide programmer mistakes like an implicit cast that cause `this` pointer adjustment in my sample.

Comment: Interesting that you may get a pointer adjustment when casting between pointer types—I haven't seen that before. Is there some page that describes how this works? I'm still don't see how that is relevant in this case, though. I'm not casting between subclasses and superclasses, so I won't have pointer adjustment, right?

Comment: Well, another reason to **not** use `void *` as many people are not aware of that. See [Does this pointer adjustment occur for non-polymorphic inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372365/does-this-pointer-adjustment-occur-for-non-polymorphic-inheritance) and [Base pointer offset adjustment for multiple inheritance](https://www.nextptr.com/question/a6212602/base-pointer-offset-adjustment-for-multiple-inheritance) for explanation.

Comment: Essentially, if you convert a type to `void*` then you must convert to the exact same type (and not a base, sibling or derived class) for the behavior to be defined as the layout is implementation defined. The **standard** would define it more precisely but it is always preferable to avoir casting and conversion to `void *` if possible. If not, then do it a localized as possible (ideally a single place for conversion for each direction) as it simplify maintenance if hierarchy need to be updated. Things like the presence of a virtual table could also affect the layout.